# Alternative to http://<site>/_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx in sharepoint 0365?

Tags: sharepoint-online

My requirement is based on the usergroup a person belong I need to hide/disable certain field in a form.

So I thought of using  `http://<site>/_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx?WSDL` is not available to get the usergroup info and create a formatting rule to decide.

But I don't see this option(usergroup.asmx) in sharepoint 365 .

What is the alternative? Or any other approach I can use to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Alternatively,** You can hide a field in the form based on user group via **SPService** as the following:

- Edit your form as shown below.

[image]

- Add the below code in Script Editor Web part.

**[Code]**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 $().SPServices({
 operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
 userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
 async: false,
 completefunc: function(xData, Status) {

 //If the current User does belong to the group "SharePoint Group Name"
 if($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='Group Name']").length == 1)
 {
 // Hide a Field
     $('nobr:contains("Field name")').closest('tr').hide();
 } else
 {
     $('nobr:contains("Field Name")').closest('tr').show();
 }
 }
 });
});
</script>
```

> **Note:** Don't forget to change the Group name at `if($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='Group Name']").length == 1)`
>
> And Field name `$('nobr:contains("Field name")').closest('tr').hide();` and `$('nobr:contains("Field name")').closest('tr').show();`

For more details check [Show/hide a div tag based on a user group in sharepoint via SPservices](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/03/25/show-hide-div-based-user-group-in-sharepoint-via-spservices/)

Comment: Field Name I am assuming what is the name of the field  (cross checked the field name in infopath as well as SPD. I tried debugging it but ended up with this  https://portal.office.com/BoxError.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/SuiteServiceProxy.aspx 500 (Internal Server Error). Please help.

Comment: Where you try this code?

Comment: I added it as a web part in the page as mentioned.After that .Added an alert to make sure this code is being called.then I put a debugger statement.The moment I opened the control I saw this message.

Comment: Great, Is it a normal form ? or InfoPath form?

Comment: Its an info path form.